# Physics are not simulated past a certain frame?

Tags: animation, physics

I've set up the physics of a swinging wrecking ball and set the animation to run for 240 frames.  This was not long enough for the entire "swing" of the ball-and-chain.

I'm unable to reset the timeline, but I **can** set the end frame to (say) 1000 frames, but when I try to play the animation, the animation progress halts at frame 240 and I cannot get it to go any further.

There are no markers or keyframes in the timeline.

What should I do to "force reset" the animation-timeline, to allow changes to the length?

Comment: This happened to me, I copied the whole document and paste in a new one, and suddenly it worked again :/

Answer (score 23):

The problem you are having is not with timeline, but with the length of the rigid body cache.

The physics systems have cache length settings independent of the scene frame range, so you must ensure that they are set accordingly as well as setting the frame range.

To do this for rigid bodies, set the *End* frame of the cache in *Properties > Scene > Rigid Body Cache* to the last frame you want the rigid bodies to be animated:

[image]

For 2.8 The Cache settings are under Rigid Body World> Cache

[image]

If you *Baked* the simulation (rather than just playing the scene animation to make a temporary cache of the simulation), press *Free Bake* in *Properties > Scene > Rigid Body Cache* to remove and "unlock" that cache:

[image]

Comment: Just to highlight the second paragraph - This applies to **all simulations**, smoke, cloth, soft body and dynamic paint all have similar cache setups within their settings. Rigid body differs in that the cache is located within the scene settings not under physics properties, while fluid only allows you to set the folder for the cache.

Comment: @sambler Particles also have this.

Answer (score 7):

Once the Rigid Body World is created in the scene, by default, the Rigid Body Cache frame range uses the current frame range. You need to manually change it in the `Scene` -> `Rigid Body Cache`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of Blender 2.8, the menu to fix this has changed.

[image: screenshot of blender scene panel]

1. Go to your scene properties panel
2. Click the 4th icon "scene"
3. Scroll down to "Rigid Body World" and expand the settings.
4. Expand "Cache"
5. Change the "End" value from 250 to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

there seemes to be a bug in vers 2.62 with the particleSimulation cache. if your timeline range for instance is 200fr and your particle cash range is also 200, but the cash is still only calculated till frame 100, you have to change the "frame range" in the properties panel at the render dimensions panel.

Comment: For me the timeline frame range and the properties panel frame range are one and the same; changing one changes the other. This goes for modern blender (2.76b atm) as well as 2.62