# How to make a Rigid Body fall off a conveyor belt?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I've created conveyor belt and and two objects with rigid body physics.
But the first object won't fall and second object falls backwards.

How can I fix it?

[Video of the problem](http://youtu.be/Q95bsImTpt8)
[Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abc1x6r0c7fe996/beltBrain2.7z?dl=0)

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend? Without seeing the details of your setup it's hard to say what is causing this.

Comment: ok i added dropbox link

Comment: This is because the simulation is not taking the deformation of the curve modifier into account. Enable *Deforming* in the physics settings of the belt object, then it works as expected. (will add a proper answer when the question is re-opened)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the rigid body simulation is only taking the initial deformation into account, behaving as if the curve modifier is applied:

[image]

To fix this, enable *Deforming* on the belt object:

[image]

This will make the simulator take into account deformations of the object that occur during the simulation.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great awesome! ... helps me alot .. but one more question why the belt running backward with the object .. so object go to front and belt run the oposite direction?

Comment: @coder5 Wow, I didn't even notice that :P. Looks to me like a bug where the rigid body simulator takes into account the new collision bounds of the deforming mesh, but not the changed direction. To fix this, make it so the belt is animated in the same direction as the brains should go, then flip the curve object by scaling it -1 on the Z axis.

Comment: thats ok.. but i got another bugs .. when i add mutliple object on belt .. the object stop in frame 250 even the belt still running ... why is that?

Comment: @coder5 It's preferred to put separate questions in separate posts, but I think the answer to this particular question is here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6741/599