# Adding a velocity to a fixed surface?

Tags: physics

when I was working with 3DStudio the simplest way to make a conveyor belt was to add a velocity property to a fixed surface. Is there a similar thing in Blender?

Comment: Could you give some more information on what you are trying to achieve? does the conveyor belt need "real" physics, should it just move, does it need to move at all or are texture manipulations enough...? there are multiple ways to do this in blender, really depends

Comment: small objects that would fall on a surface, then slide on this surface along a direction as if this surface was a conveyor belt. Basically the same physics as if the surface was translating.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24046/how-to-make-a-rigid-body-fall-off-a-conveyor-belt https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2518/building-a-conveyor