# How can I access cloth properties via python?

Tags: python, cloth-simulation

I want to manipulate options like *Disk Cache* with python:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Doesn´t seem to work

Comment: Well the idea is to make a script that iterates all selected objects and activates the Disk Cache option. Maybe this should be done via bpy.ops, but I can´t find the path on the python apy

Comment: It doesn´t work. Take in consideration that in your script your accesing to a property, not to a method.  However thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Well. It would nice i f you also add the operator for current cache to bake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Direct Access

You can access all 'cloth properties' of an object by referencing the **cloth modifier**:

```
>>> bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['Cloth'].settings.mass
>>> 0.30000001192092896
>>> bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.frame_start
>>> 0
>>> bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.use_disk_cache
>>> False
```

To find the desired property you can use python's [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#dir) method, which returns a list of valid attributes for e.g.:

- `modifiers['ClothModifierName'].collision_settings`
- `modifiers['ClothModifierName'].settings`
- `modifiers['ClothModifierName'].point_cache`

which also contain all the relevant attributes.

[image]
*Click to enlarge*

---

Setting *Cache* attributes like `use_disk_cache` and `frame_start` of the active object:

```
>>> obj = bpy.context.active_object
>>> obj.modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.use_disk_cache = True
>>> obj.modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.use_disk_cache
>>> True
>>> obj.modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.frame_start = 10
>>> obj.modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.frame_start
>>> 10
```

To avoid **assignment errors** you can check the respective 'property type' by using python's built-in [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) method:

```
>>> type(bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.use_disk_cache)
>>> <class 'bool'>
>>> type(bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['Cloth'].settings.mass)
>>> <class 'float'>
```

#### Multiple Objects

In order to set the attributes for multiple 'cloth objects' I'd suggest to check if the respective object has modifiers (also see this answer: [Check if active object has a modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42080/check-if-active-object-has-a-modifier/42081#42081)) then iterate through the modifier list and check whether the type is correct:

```
import bpy

# get objects in selection
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    # check if object has modifiers
    if obj.modifiers:
        print ("has modifiers")
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            # if object has cloth modifier
            if modifier.type == "CLOTH":
                # use disk cache attribute
                print (modifier.point_cache.use_disk_cache)
                # set the attribute
                modifier.point_cache.use_disk_cache = True 
                # mass attribute
                print (modifier.settings.mass)
                # set the attribute
                modifier.settings.mass = 1.0
```

If you need to **bake the simulation** via python, see this answer: [Setting the context for cloth bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/setting-the-context-for-cloth-bake)