# Change start and end frame of rigid physics simulation with python

Tags: python, scripting, physics

I'm having a lot of difficulty trying to change the start and end frame of a rigid body physics simulation with python. Changing the settings in the UI shows the following in info view:

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 850
```

However, running this will change the end frame of the timeline, which is not what I want. I saw the following post which solves this for cloth simulation, however this doesn't work, because the rigid body physics are not employed as a "Modifier". ([Change the start frame and end frame of a bake in Blender using script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45411/change-the-start-frame-and-end-frame-of-a-bake-in-blender-using-script))

Perhaps I have to change the context and then running the above code? I would appreciate any help implementing this, or any other way to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 3):

Just figured this out, hopefully this helps someone else. If you access the point cache within the rigid body world, this has a frame start and frame end which you can change with, for example:

```
scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_start = 1
scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_end = 1000
```