# Bouncing ball stops bouncing after 250 seconds

Tags: animation, physics

I have this simple setup of a sphere and a plane. The sphere is animated the first 15 seconds and then the rigid body is turned to dynamic. When the sphere hits the plane it starts bouncing and continues to do that till frame 250 and then stops bouncing (although the animation ends at frame 1000). Why is stopping with bouncing ?

[image]

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/physics-are-not-simulated-past-a-certain-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need to set the `Rigid Body Cache` end frame to be 1000 instead of 250 as shown below:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Did not know you could bake rigid bodies. What is the advantage of baking a rigid body ?